# Polarity of Acetic Acid, Ethanol and 1-Propanol

Tags: solubility, polarity

In order to compare acetic acid, ethanol and 1-propanol in terms of solubility in hexane, I would like to order them in terms of (a)polarity.

By looking up the dipole moments, I found that these molecules can be ordered in terms of increasing polarity like this.

1-Propanol (1.68D) < Ethanol (1.69D) < Acetic acid (1.74D)

Without looking up the values for the dipole moments, how can I predict which one of these molecules will be the most/least polar?

Comment: Dipole moment should **not** be called "polarity".  It has only tangential connection with real polarity of substances which is  connected with solubility. Also all of these are miscible with hexane which is hardly deducible from dipole moments.

Comment: Alright so based on what should I order these molecules in terms of miscibility with hexane?

Comment: Miscible means it dissolves in all proportions - completely soluble.

Comment: Isn't it possible to compare these 3 molecules?

Comment: Of course it is, but not on basis of solubility in n-hexane in room temperature. There are various measures of properties of solvents, like dielectric constant, donor number.